# How do you incorporate GTD into your daily programming tasks?

Tags: productivity

David Allen's "Getting Things Done" method seems to be a very useful way of organizing tasks and getting those tasks done. Has anyone here used GTD in their day-to-day programming tasks, and if so, what's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I use Onenote w/ skydrive (which syncs with my phone). I have a GTD notebook which has a page for **Inbox, Next Actions, Waiting On, Ideas/Later** which I use GTD style (Add everything to Inbox, then at some time empty the inbox to by doing it now, put it in Next Actions or later, or delegate it, in which case it goes to Waiting On)

Apart from the above I have a separate **Projects notebook** which has a page for each project which I review each week.

Answer (score 3):

1. Whatever you use to keep track of things, make sure it is available.
2. Get in the habit of entering things.
3. I prefer something with a reminder, so I don't have to worry about it. We have alarms so we can sleep and reminders to tell us something is up. No worries.
4. Triage tasks, identify what is important, but it doesn't need to be a complicated system.

There is more to it than that. I've just scratched the surface of the entire system. Probably should do more formal planning. My workload is picking up; now may be a good time.

Comment: Your first point is super important: you can have the most kickass system imaginable but if you don't have the notebook, or whatever, to write in, it's the same as having no system.

Answer (score 0):

I always have the [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com) page open on my desktop, and the iOS app for entering the things I remember AFK.

some points:

- Use the folders for projects
- iOS can send you alerts when things are due
- you can use email reminders too
- you can sync your iCal or Outlook calendar with your Toodledo calendar